# Using EXP in equation

Tags: exponential-function

I have the following equation:

$\ y' = te^{-2t} - 2y$

Where e is the exponential function. However when I see this being used I see EXP(x) and I don't understand how i'd write the equation with that terminology. So how would I rewrite this to use EXP(x)?

Comment: $\ y' = t \exp(-2t) - 2y$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathrm{exp}(x)$ is just a different notation for $e^x$, so your equation would become $y^\prime = t\mathrm{exp}(-2t)-2y$.